# Keras: class weights (class_weight) for one-hot encoding

Tags: python, keras

I'd like to use class_weight argument in keras model.fit to handle the imbalanced training data. By looking at some documents, I understood we can pass a dictionary like this:

```
class_weight = {0 : 1,
    1: 1,
    2: 5}
```

(In this example, class-2 will get higher penalty in the loss function.)

The problem is that my network's output has one-hot encoding i.e. class-0 = (1, 0, 0), class-1 = (0, 1, 0), and class-3 = (0, 0, 1).

How can we use the class_weight for one-hot encoded output?

By looking at [some codes in Keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/d89afdfd82e6e27b850d910890f4a4059ddea331/keras/engine/training.py#L1307), it looks like `_feed_output_names` contain a list of output classes, but in my case, `model.output_names`/`model._feed_output_names` returns `['dense_1']`

Related: [How to set class weights for imbalanced classes in Keras?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess we can use `sample_weights` instead. Inside Keras, actually, `class_weights` are converted to `sample_weights`.

> sample_weight: optional array of the same length as x, containing
> weights to apply to the model's loss for each sample. In the case of
> temporal data, you can pass a 2D array with shape (samples,
> sequence_length), to apply a different weight to every timestep of
> every sample. In this case you should make sure to specify
> sample_weight_mode="temporal" in compile().

`sample_weights` is used to provide a weight for each training sample. That means that you should pass a 1D array with the same number of elements as your training samples (indicating the weight for each of those samples)

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/d89afdfd82e6e27b850d910890f4a4059ddea331/keras/engine/training.py#L1392

Comment: how does sample_weight_mode="temporal" help with multi-class one-hot encoded targets? and do you have an idea how to handle cases where each sample can take more than one class? thx

Answer (score 43):

Here's a solution that's a bit shorter and faster. If your one-hot encoded y is a np.array:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight

y_integers = np.argmax(y, axis=1)
class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y_integers), y_integers)
d_class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights))
```

`d_class_weights` can then be passed to `class_weight` in `.fit`.

Comment: For me passing `class_weight` just as an numpy array without converting it to dictionary worked in the `model.fit()` function.

Comment: @tsveti_iko sending class weights won't work for one hot encoded, `elif isinstance(class_weight, dict): ... else: return np.ones((y.shape[0],), dtype=K.floatx())` You have to provide it with sample weights, for example `class_weight.compute_sample_weight('balanced', y_train)`  using sklearn

Answer (score 7):

in `_standardize_weights`, keras does:

```
if y.shape[1] > 1:
    y_classes = y.argmax(axis=1)
```

so basically, if you choose to use one-hot encoding, the classes are the column index.

You may also ask yourself how you can map the column index to the original classes of your data.
Well, if you use the LabelEncoder class of scikit learn to perform one-hot encoding, the column index maps the order of the `unique labels` computed  by the `.fit` function. 
The doc says

> Extract an ordered array of unique labels

Example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
y=[4,1,2,8]
l=LabelBinarizer()
y_transformed=l.fit_transorm(y)
y_transormed
> array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 1]])
l.classes_
> array([1, 2, 4, 8])
```

As a conclusion, the keys of the `class_weights` dictionary should reflect the order in the `classes_` attribute of the encoder.

Answer (score 6):

A little bit of a convoluted answer, but the best I've found so far. This assumes your data is one-hot encoded, multi-class, and working only on the labels DataFrame `df_y`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a pd.series that represents the categorical class of each one-hot encoded row
y_classes = df_y.idxmax(1, skipna=False)

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Instantiate the label encoder
le = LabelEncoder()

# Fit the label encoder to our label series
le.fit(list(y_classes))

# Create integer based labels Series
y_integers = le.transform(list(y_classes))

# Create dict of labels : integer representation
labels_and_integers = dict(zip(y_classes, y_integers))

from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight

class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y_integers), y_integers)
sample_weights = compute_sample_weight('balanced', y_integers)

class_weights_dict = dict(zip(le.transform(list(le.classes_)), class_weights))
```

This results in a `sample_weights` vector computed to balance an imbalanced dataset which can be passed to the Keras `sample_weight` property, and a `class_weights_dict` that can be fed to the Keras `class_weight` property in the `.fit` method. You don't really want to use both, just choose one. I'm using `class_weight` right now because it's complicated to get `sample_weight` working with `fit_generator`.

Comment: For me passing `class_weight` just as an numpy array without converting it to dictionary worked in the `model.fit()` function.