# Class weight balancing for sequence tagging with one hot encoding output in Keras

Tags: python, keras, one-hot-encoding

I would like to train a sequence tagging model using Keras for entity recognition.

At present, my model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 32, input_length=maxlen,mask_zero=True))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(TimeDistributedDense(512, activation='softmax'))
model.add(TimeDistributedDense(256, activation='softmax'))
model.add(TimeDistributedDense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile('rmsprop', 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

My output is in one hot encoding. Given that the sequence size is not fixed, I have padded both my inputs and outputs, as follows:

```
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=maxlen)
y_train = sequence.pad_sequences(y_train, maxlen=maxlen)
```

Thus, my output looks like this:

> [[0, 0],..., [0, 0], [1, 0], ... [0,1]...,[1,0]]

And my input looks like this:

> [0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,... 37188, 21618, 36414,   420]

I am using `categorical_crossentropy` and the `rmsprop` optimizer.

The problem I have is that my classes are very unbalanced. 98% of the tokens are not entities and consequently my model is classifying everything as not an entity.

I have tried using `class_weight` for balancing the classes, but I am not sure that I know how to specify the weights for each class, given that I am using one-hot encoding. I tried feed a class weight dictionary as follows without any luck:

```
model.compile('rmsprop', 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],class_weights={1 : 0.999999999999999999, 2:0.000000000000000001,  0: 0.000000000000000001})
```

Another user seemed to have a similar problem in [Keras: class weights (class_weight) for one-hot encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481490/keras-class-weights-class-weight-for-one-hot-encoding), but the solution is not clear. Also unlike that post, in my case my output is tridimensional (`[N_Samples, N_tokes, N_Classes]`) as a I need one vector for each token.

It seems that using `class_weight` is not the right way to go for tridimensional outputs: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3653

However, I have found no documentation for using `sample_weights`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Class weight should cover your case. It seems that you set up a wrong class weight dict. Try: `class_weights={1 : 0.999999999999999999, 0:0.000000000000000001}`

Comment: Hi @MarcinMożejko. I tried using class_weight in a previous version of Keras and Tensorflow. However, in the latest version, trying to use class_weights errors: `ValueError: class_weight not supported for 3+ dimensional targets.` François himself said that we should use sample_weights for 3d+ outputs [link](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3653)