# How to calculate class weights of a Pandas DataFrame for Keras?

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I'm trying

```
print(Y)
print(Y.shape)

class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                     np.unique(Y),
                                     Y)
print(class_weights)
```

But this gives me an error:

```
ValueError: classes should include all valid labels that can be in y
```

My `Y` looks like:

```
       0  1  2  3  4
0      0  0  1  0  0
1      1  0  0  0  0
2      0  0  0  1  0
3      0  0  1  0  0
...
14992     0  0  1  0  0
14993      0  0  1  0  0
```

And my `Y.shape` looks like:
`(14993, 5)`

In my `keras` model, I want to use the `class_weights` as it is an uneven distribution:

```
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, shuffle=True, batch_size=1500, class_weights=class_weights, validation_split=0.05, verbose=1, callbacks=[csvLogger])
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by class wieghts here?

Comment: @MohitMotwani I updated the question to explain

Comment: You may refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481490/keras-class-weights-class-weight-for-one-hot-encoding

Comment: @giser_yugang Doesn't help me with my `pandas` issue specifically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create some sample data with at least one example per class

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '0': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    '1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
    '2': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    '3': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    '4': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
})
```

Stack the columns (convert from wide to long table)

```
df = df.stack().reset_index()
>>> df.head()

  level_0   level_1     0
0   0       0       0
1   0       1       0
2   0       2       1
3   0       3       0
4   0       4       0
```

Get the class for each data point

```
Y = df[df[0] == 1]['level_1']
>>> Y
2     2
5     0
13    3
17    2
21    1
29    4
```

**Compute class weights**

```
class_weights = compute_class_weight(
    'balanced', np.unique(Y), Y
)
>>> print(class_weights)
[1.2 1.2 0.6 1.2 1.2]
```

Answer (score 6):

Just transform the one-hot encoding to categorical labels:

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight

y = Y.idxmax(axis=1)

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                                  np.unique(y),
                                                  y)

# Convert class_weights to a dictionary to pass it to class_weight in model.fit
class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights))
```