# How can I compute class weights for an output that has 4 neurons with keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've seen how to do some class weight imbalance correction for a single classification. But in my case, my output layer is:

```
model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))
```

My `target` is a `DataFrame` that has:

```
       0  1  2  3
0      1  1  0  0
1      0  0  0  0
2      1  1  1  0
3      1  1  0  0
4      1  1  0  0
5      1  1  0  0
6      1  0  0  0
...   .. .. .. ..
14989  1  1  1  1
14990  1  1  1  0
14991  1  1  1  1
14992  1  1  1  0

[14993 rows x 4 columns]
```

My predictions can take the shape of one of 5 possible values:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

However, those classes certainly are not balanced. I've seen how to computer the [class weights if I have 1 target output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842067/how-to-calculate-class-weights-of-a-pandas-dataframe-for-keras) with a `softmax`, but this is slightly different.

Specifically,

```
model.fit(..., class_weights=weights)
```

How can I define `weights` in this case?

Comment: There are 5 exclusive outputs of your neural network, why cannot those be mapped onto integers 0 through 4?

Comment: Well - that would make it a categorical problem and would treat incorrectness equally. In my case, a prediction of `[1, 1, 1, 0]` is closer to `[1, 1, 1, 1]` than to `[0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: Then it sounds you have a regression problem, not a classification one. In classification there are no distances (closer) between predictions

Comment: Classically, Id agree with you that it seems like regression. But in this case it’s categorization with ordinality.

Comment: I think you should just calculate it normally.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that @DanielMöller?

Comment: `np.sum(targets, axis=-1)/len(targets)` for the negative classes, `1-weight` for the positive classes.

Comment: How do I actually set the `class_weights` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Possible solution

IMO you should use almost standard `categorical_crossentropy` and output logits from the network which will be mapped in loss function to values `[0,1,2,3,4]` using `argmax` operation (same procedure will be applied to `one-hot-encoded` labels, see last part of this answer for an example).

Using weighted `crossentropy` you can treat incorrectness differently based on the `predicted vs correct` values as you said you indicated in the comments.

All you have to do is to **take absolute value of subtracted correct and predicted value and multiply it by loss**, see example below:

Let's map each encoding to it's unary value (can be done using `argmax` as later seen):

```
[0, 0, 0, 0] -> 0
[1, 0, 0, 0] -> 1
[1, 1, 0, 0] -> 2
[1, 1, 1, 0] -> 3
[1, 1, 1, 1] -> 4
```

And let's make some random targets and predictions by the model to see the essence:

```
   correct  predicted with Softmax
0        0                       4
1        4                       3
2        3                       3
3        1                       4
4        3                       1
5        1                       0
```

Now, when you subtract `correct` and `predicted` and take absolute you essentially get weighting column like this:

```
   weights
0        4
1        1
2        0
3        3
4        2
5        1
```

As you can see, prediction of `0` while true target is `4` will be weighted 4 times more than prediction of `3` with the same `4` target and that is what you want essentially IIUC.

As [Daniel Möller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55100676/10886420) indicates in his answer I would advise you to create a custom loss function as well but a little simpler:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Output logits from your network, not the values after softmax activation
def weighted_crossentropy(labels, logits):
    return tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
        labels,
        logits,
        weights=tf.abs(tf.argmax(logits, axis=1) - tf.argmax(labels, axis=1)),
    )
```

And you should use this loss in your `model.compile` as well, I think there is no need to reiterate points already made.

### Disadvantages of this solution:

- For correct predictions gradient will be equal to zero, which means it will be harder for network to strengthen connections (maximize/minimize logits towards `+inf/-inf`)
- Above can be mitigated by adding random noise (additional regularization) to each weighted loss. Would act as a regularization as well, might help.
- Better solution might be to **exclude** from weighting case where predictions are equal (or make it 1), it would not add randomization to network optimization.

### Advantages of this solution:

- You can easily add weighting for imbalanced dataset (e.g. certain classes ocuring more often)
- Maps cleanly to existing API
- Simple conceptually and remains in classification realm
- Your model cannot predict nonexistent classification values, e.g. with your multitarget case it could predict `[1, 0, 1, 0]`, there is no such with approach above. Less degree of freedom would help it train and remove chances for nonsensical (if I got your problem description right) predictions.

**Additional discussion provided in the chat room in comments**

### Example network with custom loss

Here is an example network with the custom loss function defined above.
Your labels have to be `one-hot-encoded` in order for it to work correctly.

```
import keras    
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# You could actually make it a lambda function as well
def weighted_crossentropy(labels, logits):
    return tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
        labels,
        logits,
        weights=tf.abs(tf.argmax(logits, axis=1) - tf.argmax(labels, axis=1)),
    )


model = keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.Dense(32, input_shape=(10,)),
        keras.layers.Activation("relu"),
        keras.layers.Dense(10),
        keras.layers.Activation("relu"),
        keras.layers.Dense(5),
    ]
)

data = np.random.random((32, 10))
labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(5, size=(32, 1)))

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=weighted_crossentropy)
model.fit(data, labels, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: Is that a valid `keras` loss function? I thought we need to pass `yTrue, yPred` to the loss function

Comment: Also, my model would have to change from `model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))` to `model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))` I assume?

Comment: If you pass logits instead of `y_pred` it should be fine (e.g. your model has no activation on the last layer). Your predictions are already in the same shape as required by softmax so I guess you will be fine (might need some tuning). BTW. there is argument `from_logits` in `categorical_crossentropy` so yeah.

Comment: No, you would remove activation altogether (e.g. make it linear), `model.add(Dense(5))` as final layer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455101/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-logits-in-tensorflow) for a few words about logits if you are uncertain about the idea.

Comment: My bad, it should be fine now, improved on the logits case, so you don't have to calculate `softmax` twice.

Comment: Are we trying to maximize the loss or minimize it? Because it seems to continue to increase over successive epochs

Comment: That's expected, you are putting more  weight on the wrong classifications being "further apart" so neural network has a hard time accomodating to this assumption (0 pred with 4 target is much worse than 3 pred with 4 target, this does not happen in regular classification). Monitor other values instead of `accuracy`, e.g. average distance between `predictions` and `targets`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189830/discussion-between-szymon-maszke-and-shamoon).

Answer (score 1):

(Removed)
First, you should fix your one-hot encoding:

(Removed) pd.get_dummies(target)

Calculate each class weight by summing the amount of `np.unique(target)` and divide by `target.shape[0]`, getting proportions:

```
target=np.array([0 0 0 0], [1 0 0 0], [1 1 0 0], [1 1 1 0], [1 1 1 1])

proportion=[]
for i in range(0,len(target)):
    proportion.append([i,len(np.where(target==np.unique(target)[i])[0])/target.shape[0]])

class_weight = dict(proportion)


model.fit(..., class_weights=class_weight)
```

Comment: That's the thing - I'm not doing try `one hot`. You'll notice that my encodings are of a different form: `[0 0 0 0], [1 0 0 0], [1 1 0 0], [1 1 1 0], [1 1 1 1]`

Comment: Use np.unique for all `[0 0 0 0], [1 0 0 0], [1 1 0 0], [1 1 1 0], [1 1 1 1]` and compare amount of each in target. You will get the percentage of classes.

Comment: Answer improved @Shamoon

Comment: Is `target` my output? Meaning all of my predictions?

Comment: Yes. Your X train maps to Targets Y in training set. Your predictions are the outputs=target in test set.

Comment: I get an error:
`    [i, len(np.where(Y == np.unique(Y)[i])[0])/Y.shape[0]])
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2`

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have your targets (ground truth y) with shape `(samples, 4)`, you can simply:

```
positives = targetsAsNumpy.sum(axis=0)
totals = len(targetsAsNumpy)

negativeWeights = positives / totals
positiveWeights = 1 - negativeWeights
```

The class weights in the fit method are meant for categorical problems (only one correct class).

I suggest you create a custom loss with these. Supposing you are using `binary_crossentropy`.

```
import keras.backend as K

posWeightsK = K.constant(positiveWeights.reshape((1,4)))
negWeightsK = K.constant(negativeWeights.reshape((1,4)))

def weightedLoss(yTrue, yPred):

    loss = K.binary_crossentropy(yTrue, yPred)
    loss = K.switch(K.greater(yTrue, 0.5), loss * posWeigthsK, loss *  negWeightsK)
    return K.mean(loss) #optionally K.mean(loss, axis=-1) for further customization
```

Use this loss in the model:

```
model.compile(loss = weightedLoss, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Per-neuron errors

For this value encoding (unary, also called 'thermometer code') you can simply measure the error on each value separately and add them, using e.g. binary_crossentropy or even mean squared / mean absolute error metric. Given this output it's not really a classification problem, it's a discrete representation of a regression task; but such representations are effective in certain cases - e.g. as the paper [Thermometer Encoding: One Hot Way To Resist Adversarial Examples](https://openreview.net/forum?id=S18Su--CW) describes.

While such separate error measurements doesn't ensure that 'invalid' outputs (e.g. [1 0 0 0 1]) are impossible, they'll be very unlikely for any well-fit network, and it does have the property that, if the correct value is [1 1 1 1 0] then a prediction of [1 1 0 0 0] is "twice as wrong" as a prediction of [1 1 1 0 0]. And you don't need to adjust the 'class weights' to achieve these results.